# Get the time between when an incoming call is connected to a carrier and when the call is answered using Twilio

Tags: twilio

Is there a way to get the time between when an incoming call connects to a carrier and when it is answered using Twilio?

This is how I understand the flow for an coming call through the Twilio system:

1. Caller dials a "Twilio" number
2. Caller's carrier connects call to Twilio
3. Twilio connects to my application to ask for instructions
4. My application tells Twilio to formward the call to the callee's phone
5. Twilio connects to the callee's carrier
6. The callee's carrier locates the phone (if it is a cell phone)
7. When the callee's carrier locates the phone, the callee's phone starts ringing
8. The callee answers the phone or the calls rolls over to voicemail, either way, the call was "answered"
9. Twilio detects that the call was answered

Is there a way to get the time delta between #5 and #9?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Evangelist here.

The upshot is a simple no. This data isn't exposed through Twilio's API ([see the REST Docs for a call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call)). Is there a particular reason you need this data?

Comment: Yes, that time would help me determine weather someone picked up the call or let it roll over to voicemail.

Comment: Interesting. We do have some Answering Machine detection (https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/can-twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine). Your only other option at the moment is to poll the API to monitor when the call is `queued` and `ringing`, until it hits your endpoint. I'll pass your request on to engineering too.